# Is there a way to simplify this reverse-enumerator?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

We have a case where we have a hierarchical tree structure and we need to get the 'branch' of any particular node. The structure is a one-way linked-list from the child to the parent, but we want to define the branch in the direction from parent to child.

Here's an over-simplified example of the implementation we came up with.  Just wondering if there's a better/more effective way to achieve this given those constraints. Just feels verbose to me to do it this way.

```cs
#nullable enable

public class Node {

    public Node(String name, Node? parent)
        => (Name, Parent) = (name, parent);

    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public Node?  Parent { get; init; }

    IEnumerable<Node> GetBranch(){
    
        static IEnumerable<Node> getBranchReversed(Node? node) { 
    
            while (node is not null) {
                yield return node;
                node = node.Parent;
            }
        }
    
        return getBranchReversed(this).Reverse();
    }
}
```

Only other way I can think of is to accumulate into a list where I insert into the first position, then just return the list (typing this from my memory so it may not compile...)

```cs
ReadOnlyCollection<Node> GetBranch(){

    Node? node = this;
    var branch = new List<Node>();

    while (node is not null) {
        branch.insert(0, node);
        node = node.Parent;
    }

    return branch.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Again, just wondering if there's any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop instead of what while, which saves you 1 line, if you want. Ultimately though if you want to reverse a singly-linked list, you need to buffer it. `Reverse()` does this, or you could do it by hand (which would remove that local function and probably be slightly quicker, although probably not observably so), it doesn't really matter

Comment: On your edit, it would be a lot cheaper to append to the list and then reverse it I think, rather than continually bumping all elements (which is quadratic, I think)

Comment: @canton7 Wouldn't that reverse create an extra buffer internally? So wouldn't that be more memory pressure?

Comment: I think the insert is a good way, but you could also use a `Stack<T>`.

Comment: Returning `new List<Node>().Reverse()` doesn't create a new buffer, just a reverse enumerator. Even if you reversed the list in-place, that's linear. When you insert, all subsequent entries have to be copied to the slot to their right, which is quadratic

Comment: @canton7 Maybe I would have to look at the implementation of `Reverse()`. If it is a native list function, then I would understand that it does not need a buffer, but if it is an Enumerable extension, then I'm not sure how it works without a buffer.

Comment: @canton7 I just looked at the source of Enumerable and it uses a buffer. But there is a native version on `List<T>` so that would do nicely. Thanks for your info. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments

IEnumerable.Reverse more or less does the following

```
var buffer = new List<int>(ienumerableToReverse);
for (int i = buffer.count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    yield return buffer.items[i];
```

Something to note about this is that it will do the buffering each time the iterator is used. It has to do this since IEnumerable is lazy. If you want to keep the lazy behavior this is just about as good as you can do, whatever solution you want to use, you will need a buffer.

If you do not want the lazy behavior I would probably do the buffering myself:

```
var branch = new List<Node>();

while (node is not null) {
    branch.Add(node);
    node = node.Parent;
}
branch.Reverse();
return branch;
```

This should be better than your example since `Insert` will need to move items around for each insert causing quadratic scaling, while `.Reverse` is linear.